# How to split a Excel file with excel Macro

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a excel file and it contains 5000 record with header. Now i need to split the file to 5 different file with header row and 1000 records. These 5 files to in same path.

Comment: 1 excel file and 5 sheets.  why use a macro?  it would only take 5 minutes (ish) manually

Answer (score -1):

Writing a macro from scratch to do this is kind of hard. I figure you ask this because this whill happen more in the future and you want to do it with the click of a button instead of doing this manually every single time.

The easiest way would be to Go to menu `tools` followed by submenu `macro` and press the `record macro` button. Now, do all the steps you need to do and press the `stop` button.

It'll now ask you to save the macro either to the workbook or your personal macros folder and optionally assign a shortcut key to it.

---

If, at this stage, you want to edit your macro using advanced scripting, press Alt-F11 to open Visual Basic for Applications. You'll see the macro you just recorded here and can edit it.

If you want to add to this macro, the easiest way would be to record what you want added to a new macro, then using VBA copy/paste the text of the macro to your other macro.

If you want to go even more advanced, google can help you to actually learn visual basic for applications. Note that VB Scripts often work in VBA as well, because VB Script is actually more limited than VBA is in some ways.

---

Forgot to mention: Next time you want to run your macro, go to menu `tools`, submenu `macro`, and press the play button, then select the macro from the list, or use the keyboard shortcut you assigned when recording the macro.

Alternatively, you can create a new toolbar and create a button that runs your macro. Creating the toolbar should be quite straight forward, as its a matter of drag and drop.

Comment: Tools menu? Really? What if the OP uses a currently **supported** version of Excel? In the last seven years, no new Excel version has had a Tools menu.

Comment: Right. Forgot about the different locations these are stored per version. Unfortunately I don't know the exact location of where the macro menu is located. I know that every version has this though. I don't use MS Office myself so I can't check it for you. I just googled for a screenshot to look where it was located.

Comment: If you don't know what you are writing about, please skip the question and move on to something that you have some expertise in.